# Testing only my DefinitelyTyped project

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I've been contributing to the jquery.datatables definition in DefinitelyTyped. There are many other definition projects included in the repository, and it seems not uncommon that one or more of them fail the test runner (`npm test`). How it happens that a clean pull from the repository fails like this is beyond me. Is there a way to isolate the test runner to only my definition?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [wd39](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46530873/111794)'s answer, if there is a `tslint.json` file in the package, you can also run `npm run lint jquery.datatables` to lint and compile a specific package.

From the [DefinitelyTyped README](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#edit-an-existing-package):

> **Editing an existing package**
>   ...
>   * If there is a `tslint.json`, run `npm run lint package-name`. Otherwise, run `tsc` in the package directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can happen sometimes on such a large projects. 
But you can directly invoke TypeScript compiler on the type definitions you created with something like (assuming your project folder is **jquery.datatables**):

```
tsc --project types/jquery.datatables/tsconfig.json
```

For this the config should be valid and already written though. 
You can also try to run it directly with:

```
 tsc --noEmit types/jquery.datatables/jquery.datatables-tests.ts
```

but it can complain if you depend on other files. ***--noEmit*** option prevents TSC from outputting JavaScript code that is not needed in the repository and DefinitelyTyped's tests will complain about (unused file, you shouldn't check it in in short).

Comment: If `noEmit` is in the `tsconfig.json` then you don't need to pass it to the command line.